# Loading dictionary words into a trie

Tags: c, file, trie

I have here a program created for pset5 of the CS50 course. The program compiles correctly and does as it should. However, is there any way to improve the run time of this program? Are there any pieces of code that are redundant and can be omitted? And is there anything that can be improved on in general?

```
/*
 * Implements a dictionary's functionality.
 */

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

typedef struct trie
{
    bool word;
    struct trie* children[27];
}trie;

trie* root;

unsigned int wordCount;

// Function that frees a node from the heap.
void freenode(trie* node)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    {
        if (node->children[i] != NULL)
        {
            freenode(node->children[i]);
        }
    }

    free(node);
}

/**
 * Returns true if word is in dictionary else false.
 */
bool check(const char* word)
{
    int n = strlen(word);

    trie* node = root;

    for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        char c = tolower(word[i]);

        if (c == '\'')
        {
            // ASCII a (97) + 26
            c = 123;
        }

        struct trie* current = node->children[c-97];

        if (current == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            node = current;
        }
    }

    if (node->word == true)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Loads dictionary into memory.  Returns true if successful else false.
 */
bool load(const char* dictionary)
{
    // Open the dictionary file
    FILE* d = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (d == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    root = calloc(1, sizeof(trie));

    trie* node = root;

    for (char c = tolower(fgetc(d)); c != EOF; c = fgetc(d))
    {
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            if (node != root)
            {
                wordCount++;

                node->word = true;

                node = root;                
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (c == '\'')
            {
                c = 123;
            }

            struct trie* current = node->children[c-97];
            if (current == NULL)
            {
                node->children[c-97] = calloc(1, sizeof(trie));

                node = node->children[c-97];
            }
            else
            {
                node = current;
            }

        }
    }

    fclose(d);

    return true;
}

/**
 * Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded.
 */
unsigned int size(void)
{
    return wordCount;
}

/**
 * Unloads dictionary from memory.  Returns true if successful else false.
 */
bool unload(void)
{
    freenode(root);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please explain what this exercise is about, and make that the title of the question. See [ask]. As it stands, your title is simply an indication that the [tag:performance] tag should be applied, and we have to guess what the objective is based on the comments, which makes your code hard to review.

Answer (score 10):

- If you feel you need a comment like this:

  ```
      // ASCII a (97) + 26
      c = 123;
  ```

  it means that the code is not clear. Consider

  ```
      c = 'a' + 26;
  ```

  While we *can* figure out the significance of `26` (size of an English alphabet, right?) again it is better to be explicit. What you want is the first character beyond the `[a-z]` range, so:

  ```
      c = 'z' + 1;
  ```

  Similarly, `node->children[c-97]` should be `node->children[c-'a']`.
- The

  ```
      if (node->word == true) {
          return true;
      }

      return false;
  ```

  is a long way to say

  ```
      return node->word;
  ```
- Avoid globals. Make `load` return `root` (or `NULL` on failure), and pass `root` to `check` as a parameter.
- Test what `calloc` returns.
- `root = calloc(1, sizeof(trie));` requires the knowledge that `root` is `trie *`, and therefore results a double maintenance. A preferred idiom is

  ```
  root = calloc(1, sizeof(*root));
  ```
- Branching factor of 27 adds a huge overhead. Most nodes will use just a few pointers, so most of the allocated memory is wasted. This in turn results in poor cache utilization, and may directly affect the performance. Consider allocating just as much as you need, and searching instead of indexing. It may or may not improve performance. Profile and compare.

Comment: Small style simplification: `root = calloc(1, sizeof(*root));` --> `root = calloc(1, sizeof *root);`.  Drop `()`.

Comment: @chux Correct. I must say I never understood the rationale of mandatory parens for a type vs optional parens for a variable, and since parens _always_ work correctly I don't bother.

Comment: I rationalize the parens around a type by imagining it's like a cast, but without a value because the value itself is irrelevant.  Dunno if that helps, but it makes some kind of twisted sense to me!

Answer (score 6):

To improve performance replace the multiple `calloc()` with a single `calloc()` using size computed from the input file size.

This line appears to be incorrect:

```
for (char c = tolower(fgetc(d)); c != EOF; c = fgetc(d))
```

because none of the chars after the first is converted to lowercase. Replace with a while loop:

```
while ((char c= tolower(fgetc(d))) != EOF)
```

Comment: `(char c= tolower(fgetc(d))) != EOF` is an infinite loop on systems where `char` is unsigned.  Better to use `int ch`.

Comment: This doesn't work. I get an error saying error: expected expression
    `while (int c = tolower(fgetc(d)) != EOF)`. I have defined c before the while loop with: `int c= tolower(fgetc(d));`

Comment: @chux When I do that, I get 6 errors telling me there's 'use of undeclared identifier 'c'' and error: expected ')'
    while ((char c= tolower(fgetc(d))) != EOF)
                 ^
dictionary.c:92:12: note: to match this '('
    while ((char c= tolower(fgetc(d))) != EOF)
           ^
dictionary.c:92:40: error: expected expression
    while ((char c= tolower(fgetc(d))) != EOF)

Comment: @zalidael Yes, of course,  There should be one declaration before the `while()` loop.  `int ch;` and none in the loop `while ((c = tolower(fgetc(d)) != EOF) { ... }`  (Also cleaning up some comments here.)

Comment: @chux It compiles, but I had to add `c = fgetc(d);` just at the end of the while loop for the program to actually work correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Avoid magic numbers.

```
// Function that frees a node from the heap.
void freenode(trie* node) {
    // for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof node->children / sizeof node->children[i]; i++)

    // or a bit cleaner
    size_t n = sizeof node->children / sizeof node->children[0];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

Minor: A simple pointer test is equivalent to testing against `NULL`.

```
    // if (node->children[i] != NULL) {
    if (node->children[i]) {
        freenode(node->children[i]);
    }
```

A C's `free()` allows `free(NULL)`. I recommend that functionality for `freenode()`, which otherwise is UB.

```
void freenode(trie* node) {
    if (node) {
      ...
    }
}
```

---

Use `size_t` as the right-sized type for array indexing and sizing.  It is the type returned by `strlen()`.  `int` may be too small.

```
bool check(const char* word) {
  // int n = strlen(word);
  size_t n = strlen(word);
```

---

`islower()` is defined for `int` values in the range of `unsigned char` and `EOF`.  Highly portable code accounts for that.

```
// char c = tolower(word[i]);
char c = tolower((unsigned char) word[i]);
```

---

GTG

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However when I try to add the for loop you mentioned I get the following error: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false.

Comment: @zalidael Unclear.  What exactly is the line of code you added?

Comment: I added size_t n = sizeof node->children[i] / sizeof node->children[i][0];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) in replacement for the for loop.

Comment: If I'm being more clear, I added size_t n = sizeof node->children[i] / sizeof node->children[i][0];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) gives me error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'.

Comment: @zalidael  Answer amended.  Use `size_t n = sizeof node->children[0] / sizeof node->children[0][0];`

Comment: I should mention, when I use the for loop you specified I get a huge memory leak when using valgrind. ==4956== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4956==    definitely lost: 5,824 bytes in 26 blocks
==4956==    indirectly lost: 82,219,648 bytes in 367,052 blocks
==4956==      possibly lost: 672 bytes in 3 blocks

Comment: @zalidael Oops. Code corrected (again) `size_t n = sizeof node->children / sizeof node->children[0];`